# MapStruct in Kotlin: How to map from multiple sources into one model?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, mapstruct

Let's say I have model:

```
data class MyModel(
    var firstName: String,
    var lastName: String,
)
```

And let's say I'm attempting to map some properties into this model from my source `PersonInfo`

```
public final data class PersonInfo(
    val firstName: String,
    val lastName: String,
)
```

This is easy enough; I just run

```
fun persontoToModel(personInfo: PersonInfo): MyModel
```

---

Now let's say MyModal is now:

```
data class MyModel(
    var firstName: String,
    var lastName: String,
    var dateOfBirth: String,
    var licenseNumber: String,
)
```

Let's also say not all of this information is available in `PersonInfo`. Instead, `dateOfBirth` is available in `PersonDetails`, and `licenseNumber` is available in `PersonDocuments`, both of which also include a bunch of other properties that I don't necessarily need to map in this case.

PersonDetails and PersonDocuments:

```
public final data class PersonDetails(
    val dateOfBirth: LocalDate,
    val weight: String,
    val height: String,
    val eyeColor: String,
)

public final data class PersonDocuments(
    val licenseNumber: String,
    val passportNumber: String,
    val socialSecurityNumber: String,
)
```

From my understanding from the documentation, I can manually map these fields by specifying them with the source in a `Mapping` annotation as follows:

```
@Mapping(source="personDetails.dateOfBirth", target="dateOfBirth")
@Mapping(source="personDocuments.licenseNumber", target="licenseNumber")
@BeanMapping(ignoreUnmappedSourceProperties = [ all the other stuff I don't need])
fun persontoToModel(personInfo: PersonInfo, personDetails: PersonDetails, personDocuments: PersonDocuments): MyModel
```

Except this doesn't work. First and foremost, the second mapping annotation is highlighted as error with the reason "This annotation is not repeatable." I'm not sure if it's a Kotlin thing, since the documentations on MapStruct seem to only use Java examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Mappings(
  Mapping(source="personDetails.dateOfBirth", target="dateOfBirth"),
  Mapping(source="personDocuments.licenseNumber", target="licenseNumber")
)
@BeanMapping(ignoreUnmappedSourceProperties = [ all the other stuff I don't need])
fun persontoToModel(personInfo: PersonInfo, personDetails: PersonDetails, personDocuments: PersonDocuments): MyModel
```

> As of Kotlin 1.1, repeated annotations are not supported (see
> [KT-12794](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-12794)). You have to wrap the Mapping-Annotation in a
> Mappings-Annotation.

[Source](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples/tree/master/mapstruct-kotlin#multiple-mappings)